# Residue computation

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus

> Define $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1-z}$. Compute $\textrm{res}_{z=0}f(z)$.

Attempt: Consider the Maclaurin series of $e^z-1-z=\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$, so we can write

\begin{equation}
f(z)=\frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots}
\end{equation}

However, if this were to be written as a power series, there would be no $\frac{1}{z}$ term, and so the residue at $0$ is $0$ - is this correct?

Comment: How do you figure there’s no $1/z$ term?

Comment: I make it, $-2/3$.

Comment: Hint: do you know [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles) result for higher-order poles' residues? For small $z$, $f\sim\frac{2}{z^2}$, i.e. the pole at $0$ is of second order, so the residue is$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^2}{e^z-1-z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{2z(e^z-1-z)-z^2(e^z-1)}{(e^z-1-z)^2}.$$If you expand the numerator and denominator to leading order, you'll find each is $O(z^4)$, and @FShrike has the correct limit.

Comment: @FShrike I don't see how you got that, could you explain please?

Comment: Abezhiko’s answer is essentially what I did, it’s nice and simple. In general polynomial division is your friend

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+ . . .}$$
We can write this as
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 \left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{z}{3!}+ . . .\right)}$$
Let
$$g(z) = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{z}{3!}+ . . .\right)}$$
Since the function $g(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$

We can write the $f(z)$ as
$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z^2}$$

Hence the $f(z)$ has pole of order $2$ at $z=0$

**EDIT : For calculation of residue**

We can calculate the residue of $m^{th}$ order pole as
$$Res_{z=z_0}f(z)= \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}[(z-z_0)^m f(z)]$$
where $m$ is order of pole.

We have pole of order $2$ at $z=0$, therefore
$$Res_{z=0} f(z) = \frac{1}{(2-1)!}\frac{d}{dz}[z^2\frac{g(z)}{z^2}]$$
$$Res_{z=0} f(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{z}{3!}+\frac{z^2}{4!} . . .\right)}\right]$$
now
$$   Res_{z=0} f(z) = {2!}\frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{2!z}{3!}+\frac{2!z^2}{4!} . . .\right)}\right] $$
we can write it as

$$  Res_{z=0} f(z) = {2!}\frac{d}{dz}\left[{1+\left(\frac{2!z}{3!}+\frac{2!z^2}{4!} . . .\right)}\right]^{-1} $$
Expanding the above term as $(1+x)^{-1}$

$$ Res_{z=0} f(z) = {2!}\frac{d}{dz}\left[{1-\left(\frac{2!z}{3!}+\frac{2!z^2}{4!} . . .\right) +\left(\frac{2!z}{3!}+\frac{2!z^2}{4!} . . .\right)^2+ . . . }\right]$$
Differentiating,
$$Res_{z=0} f(z) = 2\left[-\frac{2!}{3!}-\frac{2(2)z}{4!}-...\right]$$

It is clear from the above term that the expansion further does *NOT* contains the terms $\frac{1}{z}$ we can calculate the residue as the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$
term in the expansion. That is
$$  Res_{z=0} f(z) = -2/3$$

Comment: How do we compute the residue from this though?

Comment: @alidixon222 It is not a very clear hint. It suggests we use the pole-of-order-2 formula for the residue

Comment: The above explanation for residue calculation is a long method as compared to @Abezhiko and basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

More explicitly, you have
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \ldots} = \frac{2}{z^2} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{z}{3} + \ldots} = \frac{2}{z^2} \left(1 - \frac{z}{3} + \mathcal{O}(z^2)\right) = \frac{2}{z^2} - \frac{2/3}{z} + \mathcal{O}(1),
$$
using the first terms of the geometric series for $|z| \ll 1$, hence $\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}(f(z)) = -2/3$.